# SQL for Split cell value into rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following record

```
"NO" "EXECQTY" "PRNO"
"WDNSLR/1" "10" "~PRSLR/00001~,~PRSLR/00002~,~PRSLR/00003~,~PRSLR/00004~"
```

and want to display like this

```
"NO" "EXECQTY" "PRNO

"WDNSLR/1" "10" "PRSLR/00001"

"WDNSLR/1" "10" "PRSLR/00002

"WDNSLR/1" "10" "PRSLR/00003

"WDNSLR/1" "10" "PRSLR/00004
```

**Note**
 double quotes use to show the to differentiate column value

Comment: is this column name `NO" "EXECQTY" "PRNO`

Comment: Yes and PRNO Contain multiple values

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what you actually need is splitting the contents of the PRNO column into rows and joining it back to original table.

This would be the table:

```
declare @t table (NO varchar(20), EXECQTY varchar(20), PRNO varchar(100))
insert @t values ('WDNSLR/1', '10', '~PRSLR/00001~,~PRSLR/00002~,~PRSLR/00003~,~PRSLR/00004~')
```

And this would be the code:

```
select t.no, t.execqty, replace(f.item, '~', '') as prno
from @t t
cross apply (
    select 
        item = ltrim(rtrim(substring(t.prno, [number],
        charindex(',', t.prno + ',', [number]) - [number])))
    from (select number = row_number() over (order by name) from sys.all_objects) as x
    where number <= len(t.prno) and substring(',' + t.prno, [number], len(',')) = ','
) f
```

It's self-contained, but I would suggest using real Numbers table instead of creating the sequence every time on fly. Also, the subquery could be easily converted to a UDF.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Any particular reason for not accepting it then?